# using diff to compare a file and a directory

Tags: usb, directory, diff

there is probably a simpler way to do this but I ran ls on the /media/user directory with no usb storage plugged in and saved the output to a file and I wanted to use diff to compare the file with a new usb plugged in  and compare the file with the /media/user directory so that it detects the new directory in /media from the usb

I've used so far

```
ls > usbmedia.diff 
diff /home/user/desktop/scripts/usbmedia.diff /media/user/
```

the output I get is `no /media/user/usbmedia.diff` file so it is looking for a file of the same name but how do I get the diff command to not do that and compare the directory with the file

Comment: What exactly do you want? You want to detect if there is new USB devices plugged in?

Comment: yeah basically I just want to detect the newly mounted media and know what it is exactly and I was kind of just practicing scripts and trying out new things there wasn't really a goal in mind

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly right.

`/tmp` is better practice:

```
#!/bin/bash

while:                                            # Go forever.
    ls /media/<USERNAME>/ > /tmp/media.diff
    sleep 10
    ls /media/<USERNAME>/ > /tmp/mediacompare.diff
    diff /tmp/media.diff /tmp/mediacompare.diff
done
```

Comment: I just wrote the script for this out and my bash outputs: line 8: Syntax error: expected end of file im still fairly new to scripting but I'm assuming there has to be an end or something maybe like brackets?

Comment: Sorry, added the done.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$ ls /media/user/ > /home/user/desktop/scripts/usbmedia.diff
```

Then plug in your device

```
$ diff /home/user/desktop/scripts/usbmedia.diff <(ls /media/user/)
```

**<()** this is called **process substitution**

You could read about **process substitution** `<()` [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17107/process-substitution-and-pipe)

Comment: This worked great just tested it out thank you very much i owe you an upvote as soon as I get the rep

Comment: If this is that answer that worked, you can click the tick, below the down arrow. That gives them 15 and you 2.