# How to compare output of a running process?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am running a benchmark on [gem5 simulator](http://www.gem5.org/), which keeps printing output to terminal while its running. I already stored a sample run of the same benchmark in a [text file](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8716346/).

So now I want to compare the output stream being printed to the console with the text file of previous golden run. If there is a difference in with the output compared to the text file, the simulation should be terminated automatically.

The benchmark takes lot of time to run. I am only interested in the first error in the current run, so that I can save time of waiting till execution to complete to compare both outputs.

Comment: Do you mean something like comparing the output of each run? Like running `diff` on the command line? Like this?  http://askubuntu.com/a/511182/75166

Comment: No, I want to compare at runtime itself. diff can be used only after I finish the current run

Comment: You mean you want to compare the output from one run with the currently running one and then under some conditions you want to automatically stop the current one? Can you upload your "golden run" to pastebin.ubuntu.com so we can further analyze it? Please edit your question to add the pastebin-link.

Comment: could you clarify a bit more? benchmarks will probably *always* show a difference. I don't think you can take snapshots of a running stream, unless it is built-in like in `top` command.

Comment: @MadMike Yeah you understood it right! Its a sequence of results of some mathematical operations from basicmath benchmark.

Comment: @JacobVlijm No, basicmath benchmark has a standard output value set. It gets corrupted only when there is a fault injection during execution.

Comment: Here is the golden run output text file. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8716346/

Comment: I am still playing around a bit, I might have found a way to fetch and automatically analyze the output while the process is running etc. What is the command to start the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not resist puzzling a bit further on finding a proper way to compare the output of a *running proces* (in the terminal) against a "golden run" file, as you mention it.

#### How to catch the output of the running process

I used the `script` command with the `-f` option. This writes the current (textual) terminal content to a file; the `-f` option is to update the output file on each write event to the terminal. The script command is made to keep record of everything that happens in a terminal window.
The script below imports this output periodically.

#### What this script does

If you run the script in a terminal window, it opens a second terminal window, initiated with the `script -f` command. In this (second) terminal window, you should run your command to start the benchmark process. While this benchmark process produces its results, these results are periodically (every 2 seconds) compared to your "golden run". If a difference occurred, the differing output is displayed in the "main" (first) terminal and the script terminates. A line appears, in the format:

```
error: ('Solutions: 13.811084', 'Solutions: 13.811084 aap noot mies')

explanation:

error: (<golden_run_result>, <current_differing_output>)
```

After this output, you can safely close the second window, running your tests.

#### How to use

- Copy the script below into an empty file.
  When you look at your "golden run" file, the first section (before the actual test starts) is irrelevant and might differ on different systems. Therefore you need to define the line where the actual output begins. In your case I set it to:

  ```
  first_line = "**** REAL SIMULATION ****"
  ```

  change it if necessary.
- Set the path to your "golden run" file.
- Save the script as `compare.py`, run it by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/compare.py
  ```

  `
- a second window opens, saying `Script started, the file is named </path/to/file>`
- in this second window, run your benchmark test, the first differing result appears in the first window:

[image]

#### How I tested

I created a small program that prints the lines of an edited version of your golden run, one by one. I made the script compare it to the original "golden run" file.

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os
import time

home = os.environ["HOME"]

# files / first_line; edit if necessaary
golden_run = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/log_example"
first_line = "**** REAL SIMULATION ****"

# don't change anything below
typescript_outputfile = home+"/"+"scriptlog.txt"
# commands
startup_command = "gnome-terminal -x script -f "+typescript_outputfile
clean_textcommand = "col -bp <"+typescript_outputfile+" | less -R"
# remove old outputfile
try:
    os.remove(typescript_outputfile)
except Exception:
    pass
# initiate typescript
subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", startup_command])
time.sleep(1)
# read golden run
with open(golden_run) as src:
    original = src.read()
orig_section = original[original.find(first_line):]
# read last output of current results so far
def get_last():
    read = subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", clean_textcommand]).decode("utf-8")
    if not first_line+"\n" in read:
        return "Waiting for first line"
    else:
        return read[read.find(first_line):]
    with open(typescript_outputfile, "wt") as clear:
        clear.write("\n")
# loop
while True:
    current = get_last()
    if current == "\n":
        pass
    else:
        if not current in orig_section and current != "Waiting for first line":
            orig = orig_section.split("\n")
            breakpoint = current.split("\n")
            diff = [(orig[i], breakpoint[i]) for i in range(len(breakpoint)) \
                    if not orig[i] == breakpoint[i]]
            print("error: "+str(diff[0]))
            break
        else:
            pass
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `diff` util.

Suppose you have [your](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8716346/) golden file, and [another](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8716509/) that I changed.

I don't have your program running, so I wrote this simulation:

```
#!/bin/bash
    while read -r line; do
        echo "$line";
        sleep 1;
    done < bad_file
```

It reads from [another](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8716509/) file (bad_file), and output line by line every second.

Now running this script, and redirect it output to `log` file.

```
$ simulate > log &
```

Also I wrote checker script:

```
#!/bin/bash

helper(){
    echo "This script takes two file pathes as arguments."
    echo "$0 path/to/file1 path/to/file2"
}

validate_input(){
    if [[ $# != 2 ]]; then 
        helper
        exit 1
    fi

    if [[ ! -f "$1" ]]; then
        echo "$1" file is not exist.
        helper
        exit 1
    fi
    if [[ ! -f "$2" ]]; then
        echo "$2" file is not exist.
        helper
        exit 1
    fi
}

diff_files(){
# As input takes two file and check
# difference between files. Only checks
# number of lines you have right now in
# your $2 file, and compare it with exactly
# the same number of lines in $1
    diff -q -a -w <(tail -n+"$ULINES" $1 | head -n "$CURR_LINE") <(tail -n+"$ULINES" $2 | head -n "$CURR_LINE")
}

get_curr_lines(){
# count of lines currenly have minus ULINES
    echo "$[$(cat $1 | wc -l) - $ULINES]"
}

print_diff_lines(){
    diff -a -w --unchanged-line-format="" --new-line-format=":%dn: %L" "$1" "$2" | grep -o ":[0-9]*:" | tr -d ":"
}

ULINES=15 # count of first unused lines. How many first lines to ignore

validate_input "$1" "$2"
CURR_LINE=$(get_curr_lines "$2") # count of lines currenly have minus ULINES

if [[ $CURR_LINE < 0 ]];then
    exit 0
fi

IS_DIFF=$(diff_files "$1" "$2")
if [[ -z "$IS_DIFF" ]];then
    echo "Do nothing if they are the same"
else
    echo "Do something if files already different"
    echo "Line number: " `print_diff_lines "$1" "$2"`
fi
```

Don't forget to make it executable `chmod +x checker.sh`.

This script takes two argument. First argument is path to your golden file, second argument path to your log file.

```
$ ./checker.sh path_to_golden path_to_log
```

This checker count number of lines you have right now in your `log` file, and compare it with exactly the same number of lines in `golden_file`.

You run checker every second, and execute kill command if needed

If you want you can write bash function to run `checker.sh` every second:

```
$ chk_every() { while true; do ./checker.sh $1 $2; sleep 1; done; }
```

---

**Part of previous answer about diff**

You can compare them line by line as text file

From `man diff`

```
NAME
   diff - compare files line by line

   -a, --text
          treat all files as text

   -q, --brief
          report only when files differ

   -y, --side-by-side
          output in two columns
```

If we compare our files:

```
$ diff -a <(tail -n+15 file1) <(tail -n+15 file2)
```

We will see this output:

```
2905c2905
< Solutions: 0.686669
---
> Solutions: 0.686670
2959c2959
< Solutions: 0.279124
---
> Solutions: 0.279125
3030c3030
< Solutions: 0.539016
---
> Solutions: 0.539017
3068c3068
< Solutions: 0.308278
---
> Solutions: 0.308279
```

It show the line that differs

And here is final command, I assuming you don't want to check first 15 lines:

```
$ diff -y -a <(tail -n+15 file1) <(tail -n+15 file2)
```

It will show you all differences in two columns. If you only want to know is there any difference use this:

```
$ diff -q -a <(tail -n+15 file1) <(tail -n+15 file2)
```

It will print nothing if files are the same

Comment: This doesn't compare the output while its running and it does not stop the programm if it differs.

Comment: Here we have only one text file. I am trying to compare it with the currently running benchmark on terminal. Creating the second text file to compare using diff will not be useful for me as each run takes 20 minutes. I want to terminate the current execution as soon as I get a mismatch with the first text file.

Comment: @c0rp can you make it a little clear? What do you mean by test3? and should I replace $1 $2 with my file path?

Comment: That's awesome! It will help a lot. Excuse me if I am being greedy, but can we make this script run periodically in a loop rather than manually executing it every-time? As soon as I see a difference arises I can terminate the loop..

Comment: It helped a lot! Thank you so much @c0rp ! Someone please up vote the ans. I don't have enough points to up vote.

Comment: I think it is printing the last line number of text file instead of line with error. (Not a big issue, Can adjust if its complex)

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea how complicated your input data is but you could use something like `awk` to read each line as it comes in and compare it to a known value.

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5; do echo $i; sleep 1; done | \
  awk '{print "Out:", $0; fflush(); if ($1==2) exit(0)}'
Out: 1
Out: 2
```

In this case I'm feeding in a time-delayed stream of numbers and `awk` is running until the first variable in the input (the *only* variable here) equals 2, then exits and in doing so arrests the stream.

Comment: @MadMike my output is in a text file like this http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8716346/ .I want my runtime stream to get compared with the lines in this text file. I can terminate as soon as there is a mismatch.